# Interactive marker does not affect on a Goal State

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys! I need some help. I have successfully launched rviz with moveit planing library with my extremely simple test robot arm. I'm able to set a Goal State from the Planning tab (into a random position).
But when I try to set the Goal State (either the Start State) with an Interactive Marker it does not affect the Goal state and doesn't change it's position.
Only if I check the "Allow Approximate IK Solutions" check-box I'm able to set the approximate position of a Goal with the Interactive Marker. However even with the "Allow Approximate IK Solutions" checked I can only move the Goal with Interactive Marker in a limited range (can't rotate around the link1, for example).
Below is the link to screen-shots, which could help me to explain myself better, maybe...
Since I do not have enough carma I'v uploaded screen-shots to google:

https://plus.google.com/photos/118074651943455816453/album/5937238414252443713/5937238987547825202?authkey=COmOl_qGi5uLsgE

Thanks ahead for a help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92846/interactive-marker-does-not-affect-on-a-goal-state/) by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is solved. I have set the position_only_ik: True in kinematics.yaml file and this has solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [maska](https://answers.ros.org/users/7951/maska/) with karma: 61 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mfran89](https://answers.ros.org/users/10546/mfran89/) on 2014-01-17**:
Could you elaborate a little bit more about this? I also had the same problem and once I checked the "allow approximate IK solution" my RVIZ simulation worked fine. But are you saying that this option is not the correct way of controlling the RVIZ arm? Also what did you mean by "set the position_only_ik: True in kinematics.yaml file"? I looked through my .yaml file and did not see parameter like the one you mentioned. Any help would greatly be appreciated.
mfran89 (24 mins ago)